Two dimensional colormaps in TikZ
I have a two-dimensional data on a grid and would want to color the image according to a two-dimensional colormap.
What I have in mind is something like this: https://colorstamps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Is it possible to create such a two-dimensional colormap in TikZ?
What could also help would be to just supply the rbg value in the data file directly if that is possible. Then I could preprocess my data with the python package above.
For those interested, here is a little more detail:
I have a vector field in two dimensions, i.e., an arrow is based on every grid point.
For every vector, I consider its angle (e.g., with reference to the x-axis).
The change of this angle from one vector to its right neighbor is the first value that I would like to visualize, e.g., with a colormap from red to yellow.
The change of the angle from one vector to its bottom neighbor is the second value that I want to visualize, e.g., with colors from green to blue.
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x y u1 u2 hspeed vspeed
0 0 0.0 1.0 -0.07188070003177315 -0.0
0 1 0.0 1.0 -0.07158946673346171 -0.0
0 2 0.0 1.0 -0.057094854460731724 -0.0
0 3 0.0 1.0 -0.03347963084006465 -0.0
0 4 0.0 1.0 -0.013083734149875044 -0.0
0 5 0.0 1.0 -0.0 nan
1 0 0.07187841179982613 0.9974176946309252 -0.16542463104943467 0.0
1 1 0.0716699763470131 0.9974385683626027 -0.15104763002399885 0.010812987135312492
1 2 0.05760105950257583 0.9983705315173668 -0.11961648479850642 0.01707891121473561
1 3 0.03546991662566399 0.9994396095068135 -0.07492312813401608 0.012191643444346496
1 4 0.016115521194477407 0.9999144091713406 -0.030265879212531245 0.006085005830078574
1 5 0.003940376967159538 1.0000035763153805 -0.008527449417517258 nan
2 0 0.23517679411874276 0.9719542680489118 -0.2007478284251669 0.013571574620847744
2 1 0.22107906018375667 0.9752673290655167 -0.1781482588471185 0.04416107696524271
2 2 0.1768459023077889 0.9842718028303925 -0.1291405028338838 0.0655102235746852
2 3 0.11129346442851931 0.993803923518852 -0.07243978603606352 0.06328213242230141
2 4 0.04790839626193615 0.9988554473292303 -0.030208991340661594 0.02634384336170812
2 5 0.019045126229605237 0.9998850206426312 -0.0 nan
3 0 0.4243847827038066 0.9055079127644249 -0.16493751933804845 0.03642090077752451
3 1 0.39047140444230266 0.9206178084446903 -0.14467743743988068 0.09394143470159227
3 2 0.3023626146420581 0.9531933715056674 -0.09609670434277486 0.12292014315406069
3 3 0.18318456220786117 0.9830813887668027 -0.04881549383486099 0.10512208992198577
3 4 0.07881150083332174 0.9969090253959793 -0.01854551421503562 0.045985870474352236
3 5 0.030907805459045295 0.9995966735733649 -0.0 nan
4 0 0.5681397813422335 0.8230946719058552 -0.0720048406975582 0.05580207859224652
4 1 0.5191780135514953 0.8546742056451558 -0.05560864838708198 0.14245342512737572
4 2 0.3924932171923176 0.919761944079045 -0.03608194237045221 0.1702016578597019
4 3 0.23099315875704043 0.9729554344473551 -0.014879059028346292 0.13458732385991282
4 4 0.09834462622163359 0.9951533429989254 -0.0 0.05691588141477627
4 5 0.04083303824901665 0.9992078361876273 -0.0 nan
5 0 0.6317622825455238 0.7757060129736967 nan 0.07210927678937461
5 1 0.5680320711005623 0.8231727020101057 nan 0.1631847747547957
5 2 0.4258825101573337 0.904791860695396 nan 0.1918868922417908
5 3 0.24544825826784486 0.9694097046597004 nan 0.14734169413849216
5 4 0.1003692435477107 0.9949656739200117 nan 0.057738068701983246
5 5 0.04212594312094239 0.9991354453053234 nan nan
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.18,
}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfplotsset{%
    colormap={bluegreen}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,255,0); rgb255(1cm)=(0,0,255)},
    colormap={redyellow}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,0,0); rgb255(1cm)=(255,255,0)}
}


\newcommand{\m}{5}
\newcommand{\n}{6}
\newcommand{\arrscale}{0.8}
\newcommand{\tipscale}{0.6}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xmaxvalue{\m + 1.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ymaxvalue{\n + 0.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\matrixrows{int(\m + 1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\matrixcols{int(\n)}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal image,
            xmin = -1.5,
            ymin = -1.5,
            xmax = \xmaxvalue,
            ymax = \ymaxvalue,
            colorbar,
            colormap name=redyellow,
            title={horizontal angular speed},
            ]
            \addplot[
                matrix plot*,
                point meta=explicit,
                mesh/rows=\matrixrows,
                mesh/cols=\matrixcols,
            ] table [
                x expr=\thisrow{x}+0.5,
                meta=hspeed
            ] {data.dat};
            \addplot[
                black,
                quiver={u=\thisrow{u1},v=\thisrow{u2}},
                quiver/scale arrows=\arrscale,
                -{Stealth[scale=\tipscale]},
            ] table {data.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal image,
            xmin = -1.5,
            ymin = -1.5,
            xmax = \xmaxvalue,
            ymax = \ymaxvalue,
            colorbar,
            colormap name=bluegreen,
            title={vertical angular speed},
            ]
            \addplot[
                matrix plot*,
                point meta=explicit,
                mesh/rows=\matrixrows,
                mesh/cols=\matrixcols,
            ] table [
                y expr=\thisrow{y}+0.5,
                meta=vspeed,
            ] {data.dat};
            \addplot[
                black,
                quiver={u=\thisrow{u1},v=\thisrow{u2}},
                quiver/scale arrows=\arrscale,
                -{Stealth[scale=\tipscale]},
            ] table {data.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output:

The goal would be to "merge" the two plots into one.
I have done that with Python instead of TikZ using the package mentioned above. Here is the result:


Please alway make a MWE. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that No one will work on a solution to the 2D colormap, when there is no code showing 2D data or even any graph. Please make your question self contained without links(that can break in the future) to outside source. -insert pictures directly in your question (with proper accredit).

Hey @hpekristiansen. You are of course right. I did not have an MWE at the time I was asking the question. I Have added it now.

Reference picture from OP link (https://colorstamps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

The 2D colorbar can be created like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings, fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!50, outer color=transparent!100]

\pgfplotsset{
colorbar style={
width=1.5cm, height=1.5cm,
xmin=-1, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1,
xtick={}, ytick={},
xtick distance=1, ytick distance=1,
xtick pos=bottom,
ytick pos=left, yticklabel pos=left,
tick align=outside,
xlabel=$\omega$, ylabel=$\phi$,
},  
colorbar shift/.style={at=(current axis.north east), anchor=center, xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-0.5cm},
colorbar/draw/.code={
\begin{axis}[every colorbar, colorbar shift, colorbar=false]
\shade[upper left=purple!80, upper right=red!60, lower left=cyan!90!blue!60, lower right=green!60] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[white, path fading=fade out] (-0.8,-0.8) rectangle (0.8,0.8);
\end{axis}
},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis equal image,
xmin=0, xmax=199,
ymin=0, ymax=99,
y dir=reverse,
xtick distance=25,
colorbar,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The problem with creating the bar with a \shade is that there is no way of retrieving the color to use in a \draw or \addplot - so every color needs to be added manually.
This can be overcome by declaring a functional shading (\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading) this is very complicated/time consuming to set up and this warning is in the manual:

Warning: These shadings are the least portable of all and they put the
heaviest burden of the renderer. They are slow and, possibly, will not
print correctly!

An other way is to use an ordinary 1D colormap, but fake 2D in a suitable way e.g. like this:
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x y u1 u2 hspeed vspeed
0 0 0.0 1.0 -0.07188070003177315 -0.0
0 1 0.0 1.0 -0.07158946673346171 -0.0
0 2 0.0 1.0 -0.057094854460731724 -0.0
0 3 0.0 1.0 -0.03347963084006465 -0.0
0 4 0.0 1.0 -0.013083734149875044 -0.0
0 5 0.0 1.0 -0.0 nan
1 0 0.07187841179982613 0.9974176946309252 -0.16542463104943467 0.0
1 1 0.0716699763470131 0.9974385683626027 -0.15104763002399885 0.010812987135312492
1 2 0.05760105950257583 0.9983705315173668 -0.11961648479850642 0.01707891121473561
1 3 0.03546991662566399 0.9994396095068135 -0.07492312813401608 0.012191643444346496
1 4 0.016115521194477407 0.9999144091713406 -0.030265879212531245 0.006085005830078574
1 5 0.003940376967159538 1.0000035763153805 -0.008527449417517258 nan
2 0 0.23517679411874276 0.9719542680489118 -0.2007478284251669 0.013571574620847744
2 1 0.22107906018375667 0.9752673290655167 -0.1781482588471185 0.04416107696524271
2 2 0.1768459023077889 0.9842718028303925 -0.1291405028338838 0.0655102235746852
2 3 0.11129346442851931 0.993803923518852 -0.07243978603606352 0.06328213242230141
2 4 0.04790839626193615 0.9988554473292303 -0.030208991340661594 0.02634384336170812
2 5 0.019045126229605237 0.9998850206426312 -0.0 nan
3 0 0.4243847827038066 0.9055079127644249 -0.16493751933804845 0.03642090077752451
3 1 0.39047140444230266 0.9206178084446903 -0.14467743743988068 0.09394143470159227
3 2 0.3023626146420581 0.9531933715056674 -0.09609670434277486 0.12292014315406069
3 3 0.18318456220786117 0.9830813887668027 -0.04881549383486099 0.10512208992198577
3 4 0.07881150083332174 0.9969090253959793 -0.01854551421503562 0.045985870474352236
3 5 0.030907805459045295 0.9995966735733649 -0.0 nan
4 0 0.5681397813422335 0.8230946719058552 -0.0720048406975582 0.05580207859224652
4 1 0.5191780135514953 0.8546742056451558 -0.05560864838708198 0.14245342512737572
4 2 0.3924932171923176 0.919761944079045 -0.03608194237045221 0.1702016578597019
4 3 0.23099315875704043 0.9729554344473551 -0.014879059028346292 0.13458732385991282
4 4 0.09834462622163359 0.9951533429989254 -0.0 0.05691588141477627
4 5 0.04083303824901665 0.9992078361876273 -0.0 nan
5 0 0.6317622825455238 0.7757060129736967 nan 0.07210927678937461
5 1 0.5680320711005623 0.8231727020101057 nan 0.1631847747547957
5 2 0.4258825101573337 0.904791860695396 nan 0.1918868922417908
5 3 0.24544825826784486 0.9694097046597004 nan 0.14734169413849216
5 4 0.1003692435477107 0.9949656739200117 nan 0.057738068701983246
5 5 0.04212594312094239 0.9991354453053234 nan nan
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
colormap={mycm}{color=(blue); color=(green); color=(red); color=(yellow); color=(blue)},
}

\pgfplotsset{
colorbar style={
width=2cm, height=2cm,
xmin=-1, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1,
xtick={}, ytick={},
xtick distance=1, ytick distance=1,
},  
colorbar shift/.style={at=(current axis.north east), anchor=center, xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=-0.5cm},
colorbar/draw/.code={
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90}, 
every colorbar, colorbar shift, colorbar=false]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=interp,
domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1,
samples=40,
point meta min=-180, point meta max=180,
point meta rel=per plot,
] {atan2(x*cos(45)-y*sin(45),x*sin(45)+y*cos(45))};
\end{axis}
},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis equal image,
xmin=-1.5, xmax=6.5,
ymin=-1.5, ymax=6.5,
colorbar,
view={0}{90},
]
\addplot[
matrix plot*,
point meta=explicit,
mesh/rows=6,
mesh/cols=6,
] table [
y expr=\thisrow{y}+0.5,
meta=vspeed,
] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you very much for your effort and time.
The actual problem with the vector field is a bit more involved as one has to decide how to combine the hspeed and vspeed values for a cell.
However, I came to the conclusion that it would be best if I could just read the pre-computed RBG values of a file that I prepare with python and the colorstamps package. I will open a new question for this

The answer is not exactly what I wanted since it uses only the vspeed values from the data. But I will except never the less since I think an actual solution could be compiled from this.

I do not know the "colorstamps" package - is it a LaTeX package? -I can not find it. I am aware that the plot is not what you wanted - I focused on setting up the 2D colorbar, and not your actual use case - as it is far from minimal.

No its the Python package that implements the 2d colormaps.

If you want to use your Python plot inside PGFPlots e.g. to make your plot axis and more consistent with other plots in your document, you can do it with \addplot graphics page 63 in the manual.

Also a good idea. Although I would prefer to build the picture purely in TikZ if possible.
The new and strongly related question is up: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723212/rgb-values-for-pgfplot-matrixplot
