RGB values for pgfplot matrixplot
I want to build a matrix plot. But instead of having the values for the entries in the matrix I already have the rgb values for each cell.
Here is the code that I have. So far it uses only the r (red) column of the data.
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x y r g b
0 0 255.00 163.14 163.14
0 1 163.14 163.14 255.00
0 2 163.14 255.00 163.14
1 0 255.00 88.59 88.59
1 1 255.00 88.59 88.59
1 2 255.00 255.00 99.31
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.18,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal image,
            xmin = -0.5,
            ymin = -0.5,
            xmax = 1.5,
            ymax = 2.5,
            ]
            \addplot[
                matrix plot*,
                point meta=explicit,
                mesh/rows=2,
                mesh/cols=3,
            ] table [ meta=r, ] {colors.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This is what it produces:

I also have an example of what this data should look like:


I found the solution myself:
Scaling the RBG values to be from 0 to 1 one can use:
    mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
    point meta={symbolic={\thisrow{r}, \thisrow{g}, \thisrow{b}}},

to set the colors explicitly. Overall the code looks like this:
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
x y r g b
0 0 1.00 0.64 0.64
0 1 0.64 0.64 1.00
0 2 0.64 1.00 0.64
1 0 1.00 0.35 0.35
1 1 1.00 0.35 0.35
1 2 1.00 1.00 0.39
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.18,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis equal image,
            xmin = -0.5,
            ymin = -0.5,
            xmax = 1.5,
            ymax = 2.5,
            ]
            \addplot[
                matrix plot*,
                mesh/color input=explicit mathparse,
                point meta={symbolic={\thisrow{r}, \thisrow{g}, \thisrow{b}}},
                mesh/rows=2,
                mesh/cols=3,
            ] table {colors.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Or you could use point meta={symbolic={rgb255=\thisrow{r}, \thisrow{g}, \thisrow{b}}}

This would also work: point meta={symbolic={\thisrow{r}/255, \thisrow{g}/255, \thisrow{b}/255}}

Aha. Y thank you.
